# Is Hibernate with Repositories thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, repository

I have been looking for this information, and I found contradictory statements. Most of the questions and answers have been in a context where sessions are managed manually, which isn't my case. I'm using springboot repository to manage all my data, and am not managing any session manually.

Is Hibernate with repositories thread safe ? Are there any way to make it so ?

Comment: What component's thread-safety are you doubting? Your question is akin to "is Ford with air conditioning fast?".

Comment: Any, the issue is that connection are closing in the middle of the thread ("This statement has been closed"). This issue wasn't happening before using threads so that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: There are plenty of non-threadsafe classes, and if you've written broken code then you'll need to fix it.

Comment: Is there any list of non thread-safe classes ?

Comment: No. But if there were, it would be bigger than the list of thread-safe classes. You have an XY problem that you're trying to solve in a bad way mon ami, there is no magical "make my software thread-safe" trick. If you're writing a regular Spring Boot program with HikariCP, repositories and the standard stuff, it's pretty hard to write thread-unsafe programs unless you do something really strange. If you're working with WebMVC then normally you're isolated in your own thread. With Webflux it might be different.

Comment: Do you know if Cacheable is thread-safe ? It's the only "non-standard" part of the application, even tho it's relatively heavy.

Comment: [Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) is quite standard. Don't ask "is ClassX thread-safe", ask "is my code using ClassX correctly". Your code is broken, you're concentrating on code written by others (for some odd reason). You probably should be showing your code, instead of guessing about which classes might not be thread-safe (the javadoc may usually say something about thread-safety, but you shouldn't assume a class is thread-safe).